# Jquery mousemove missed some cells if hovered very fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am moving my mouse from left to right very quickly and in the event some td miss getting color.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czL5Loe4/

I have put mousemove on document yet the event is skipped sometimes particularly when moving it super fast.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("mousemove", function(e){
        if (e.which === 1) {
            var cell = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, 20));            
           if(cell.hasClass("td"))
                cell.addClass("highlighted");
            }
        }       
      );   
});
```

Sample output when moving it very fast: http://gyazo.com/223a2f19f58720fc1d34369233e07533

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Create a virtual rectangle and get all overlapping cells. This is the best what you can do.

Comment: On mousedown, you store mouse is down, and a start location. On mouseMove you check which `td`-s are under the rectangle.

Comment: Dont you understand it still? I can help you deeper if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is get movements over these elements, I would do the below. If you need to listen for more stuff it could be worked in from there.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
       $(this).addClass("highlighted");
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
       // other stuff if you want
    }
}, '.td'); // down here you pass the selector you wish to target
```

See this [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czL5Loe4/3/)

Comment: Did you understand my question? The issue that I was facing in my original answer is still there. Just try to move the mouse very quickly from left to right or right to left - you will see the cell getting skipped.

Comment: Sorry, I did missunderstand. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to get that level of control. It almost seems like it's not realy jQuery at all but rather an issue with the browser itself not recognizing a really fast swipe like the OS thinks your about to click some other program altogether.